# How to connect a 20 V/0.6 A solar panel to a 3.7v/4000mAh battery and 1amp load

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell

I have a 10 W solar panel, which I can see outputs approx 20 V in bright sunshine and is rated at approx 0.6 A.

I have a 3.7 V 4000 mAh (14.8 Wh) li-ion battery.

I want the panel and battery to form the main a power subsytem that can output 5 V at 1 A or more.

I believe I need some sort of (i) battery charge controller and (ii) output voltage regulation.

I tried [using this board](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Solar_Power_Manager) but it didn't work as expected - when there is no solar connection it is incapable of supplying a clean 5 V under load. See this [thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/t77nkf/solar_power_management_board_voltage_regulation/) for more details.

Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions? I'm a complete newbie, so please forgive if not a well framed question. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Ideally with an MPPT solar charger made for a 1S battery, followed by a boost converter to supply your 5 V output.

Comment: Spot on @winny !

Comment: ng5000, Winny's answer is so close to perfect of an answer that you should make every effort to follow it. This is just two purchases of COTS devices. (1) MPPT Li-ion 1S solar charger module that accepts your solar panel specs and provides Li-ion charging capabilities; followed by, (2) a Li-ion 5 V boost switcher that meets your needs at 5 V and works from a single Li-ion battery system. The only remaining problem to consider is how the boost switcher responds to the MPPT solar charger output vagaries. Which may or may not require something that isolates the two based on some consideration.

Comment: ng5000, Or you can [go here](https://www.st.com/en/power-management/spv1040.html#overview) and start a design process there using the SPV1040T. This is just the DC-DC conversion though. No battery charger included. You may be able to find an IC that gives you everything, though. I'll leave that for you.

Comment: Thanks all! So would [PANEL] --> [MPPT CHARGER] --> [1S BATTERY] --> [MT3608 DC-DC Booster] work? I.e. so there are 2 connections to the battery; the MPPT charger supplying current, and then wires from the battery to the booster.

Comment: I think another problem to solve is overdischarge protection. The booster side of the circuit isn't measuring battery voltage, so could over discharge the battery I think. I think I can protect that in the micro controller - if it detects battery voltage is critical it can go into a sleep mode for x hours. If after x hours battery is still critical voltage then it can sleep for x again (or some sort of back off algo). Sound legit?

Comment: Or, I could just buy a liion battery with protection circuitry built in. Thanks again all for all your comments and help.